# Error: misconfigured csrf - Express JS 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, csrf

I am trying to enable the [csrf](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf) module of Express 4 in an existing application.

I have added the following code:

```
var csrf = require('csurf')
...

app.use(csrf());
```

I have started my application and I get:

```
Error: misconfigured csrf
```

and a stack trace. Nothing else.

I have checked the documentation, but it is unclear. Can someone help? What is the minimum configuration required to use this module?

Comment: Seems like you either need to be specifying a cookie or using express sessions.

Comment: I did, I put app.use(csrf()) after app.use(cookieParser())...

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I have found the solution. The call to `app.use(csrf())` must be set after `app.use(cookieParser())` AND `app.use(session({...})`.

Comment: I had this already, but I had to put it at the bottom of my main app.js file, right before the `module.exports = app`. Worked fine until I added redis as a session.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using Redis as a session store and the server isn't running, you will also get a misconfigured error.

https://github.com/expressjs/csurf/issues/73

Comment: I was using MongoStore as a session storage and got that error too. Thanks a lot, you saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(
  sessions({
  cookieName: 'demo-session',
  secret: 'this is a secret msg',
  duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
 })
);

app.use(csurf({ sessionKey: 'demo-session' }));
```

I got the same error when the sessionKey was not the same in the session middleware and csurf. csurf uses *session* as default sessionKey if not provided. Here the sessionKey is *demo-session*, which should be the same in your session middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Install express-session and cookie-parser

```
npm i express-session
npm i -D @types/express-session
npm i cookie-parser
npm i -D @types/cookie-parser
```

Step 2: In your ***main.ts*** file in your nest js project
add the following lines of code

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'your-secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  }),
);
app.use(csurf());
```

see the following [cookie](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/cookies)
and [session](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/session) links for more details

Answer (score 0):

If declaring `csurf` below `cookieParser` still throws an error, try to add these inside `csurf`.

```js
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(csurf({ cookie: true }));
```

Answer (score 0):

//  ALWAYS USE AFTER THE SESSION CONFIG
as like

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const csurf = require('csurf')

const app = express()
app.use(session({
   secret: "your secret string. you can also save it in .env file",
   cookie: {},
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: false
}));
// then use the csurf() middleware
app.use(csurf());
```

### This works for me! You can try

Comment: express-session can cause memory leak use cookies-session instead