# Using CSRF in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, csrf

I am trying to use csrf in my NodeJS application. 
You can see the code below. When I run this code I am getting "TypeError: req.csrfToken is not a function" error.

I want to create csrf token for all requests and want to check csrf tokens in ajax calls. As I said I can not create csrf token, I am getting error. Also how can I check csrf token in ajax calls?

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Server Side:

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var csrf = require('csurf');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

/*this line commented*/
//var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: false });
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

var parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
app.use(cookieParser());

/*this line added*/
app.use(csrf({ cookie: false }));

app.use(session({
    genid: function (req) {
        return "lkgktktgjknvfndkj-dfgjnkdfkjgn-dfgdfg";
    },
    name: "mySecret",
    resave: false, // don't save session if unmodified
    saveUninitialized: false, // don't create session until something stored
    secret: 'thisIsASecret'
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken();

    next();
});

app.get('/', /*csrfProtection,*/ function (req, res) {
    res.render('index')
});

app.post('/process', parseForm, /*csrfProtection,*/ function (req, res) {
    res.send('data is being processed')
});
```

Index.jade

```
meta(name="csrf-token", content="#{csrfToken}")
block content
    input(type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="#{csrfToken}")

    |Favorite color: <input type="text" name="favoriteColor">
    button(type="submit" id="sbmt") Submit

    script(src= "/javascripts/jquery-2.2.1.js")

    script.
        $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
          var token;
          if (!options.crossDomain) {
            token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
            if (token) {
                return jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);
            }
          }
        });

        $("#sbmt").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post(
                "/process",
                {
                    //text: text,
                    _csrf : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }, function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add:

```
app.use(session({ ... });
// Add this after session
app.use(csrfProtection);
```

You need to add this AFTER the session as stated [here](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf):

> If you are setting the "cookie" option to a non-false value, then you
>   must use cookie-parser before this module. Otherwise, you must use a
>   session middleware before this module. For example: express-session
>   cookie-session

Comment: Hi I commented this line: //var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: false }); I added app.use(csrf({ cookie: false })); before session usage after cookieparser. I removed csrfProtection usage in the routes. This time it gives me "misconfigured csrf" error.

Comment: I edited my code, gives me "misconfigured csrf" error.

Comment: Thank you Michelem, it is working magically. Your help was really valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `csrf()` returns a function ([source](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf/blob/master/index.js#L61)). You need to `use` it in order to have it. What you've missed in the tutorial is:

```
var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })
app.get('/form', csrfProtection, function(req, res) {
    // pass the csrfToken to the view
    res.render('send', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() })
})
```

Here, the `csrfProtection` is actually being called, and it adds `csrfToken` method to `req`. In the other example there is:

```
app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }))
```

Which means **all** routes will use the protection and therefore no post without it would be possible.

It depends on your usage - if you want to secure all routes - use it globally (`app.use`), otherwise use it per request (as in the first example).

If you try using it in your index route you will have it, because you've used it as middleware:

```
app.get('/', csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
    res.render('index')
});
```

Comment: I edited my code, gives me "misconfigured csrf" error.

Comment: Well just google it!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997572/error-misconfigured-csrf-express-js-4

Comment: This is not a walk-me-through type of forum. You ask something, you get response. If you have other problem you keep asking new questions. And it would be nice to put some efforts and start reading the docs - it's all in there.

Comment: Hi Andrey, you are right, I got responses but responses were not enough to run my code successfully. So according to your responses I changed my code a little and I got antoher error. Also, I spent my whole day and read lots of forum to achieve what I think. After this effort I asked my question in stackoverflow. So I think I made my best effort before asking the question.(by the way I am very newbie on Node and csrf) Anyhow, thanks for your guidance